# missing attribute get in datastore's object

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This is my GAE datastore:

```
class Search(ndb.Model):
    city = ndb.StringProperty()
    counter = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed = True)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

When I run this part of code:

```
keys = Search.query(Search.city == city).fetch()

if (len(keys)==0):
    luogo = Search(city = city, counter = 1)
    luogo.put()
else:
    for key in keys:
        luogo_1 = key.get()
        luogo_1.counter = luogo_1.counter+1
        luogo_1.put()
```

my terminal says that is missing in object Search attribute get

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running

`keys = Search.query(Search.city == city).fetch()`

fetches a list of model *instances*

so

```
for key in keys:
    luogo_1 = key.get()
```

fails because *instances* don't have a `get` method.

You need to do:

`keys = Search.query(Search.city == city).fetch(keys_only=True)`

to fetch a list of keys, or treat `keys` as a list of instances rather than keys, and omit the `key.get()` call.

Comment: However this is somewhat redundant if the intent is to fetch the entities.  The result of `Search.query(Search.city == city).fetch()` is a list of entities so you don't need to use the key and fetch them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because `key` object doesn't have `get()` method:

```
luogo_1 = key.get()
```

Use python [dir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function, it helps me a lot